# How can a repair a hole in my sheepskin jacket?

Tags: sewing, leather

I mistakenly put my jacket on a rounded hook. The weight of the jacket put it through. Now, I have a thumb size hole under my collar. I could leave it but I worry it could get larger over time and would like to stop that.

I don't think that I can sew it. I feel the thread would just tear through it as I was tightening the seam. The jacket *feels* thin there.

Is a leather patch the ideal way to go here just to be sure the fix is more long term?

What should I do to repair the thumb sized hole in my jacket?

Answer (score 7):

I'd suggest you use leather glue to glue a patch from the inner side (with either leather or cloth - whatever suits the design of your jacket best). You can get creative with that and glue some logo or image instead of just a blunt patch (if so, you can do it on the outer side instead of the inner side). But from what I can visualise the leather is not only torn, but also stretched and deformed at the place. If that is the case, I'd suggest before you glue it to try to bring it back to its original shape as much as possible by dampening the affected place with cool water. Water will cause the stretched leather to shrink slightly once dry but while it is still damp you can also stretch it a bit if necessary. Do that only if you are sure water won't damage the jacket.

Comment: +1 good answer, welcome to the site. Next to glue you can also sew on a patch if the leather of the jacket around the patch feels stronger. If at all possible I would use both glue and sewing.